# Is It Possible To Recover Uninstalled Program From Operating System Lost Due to Formatting

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, google-chrome, uninstall

A while back I had run Google Chrome on XP Some time later I had it uninstalled.Then some time later I also had my disk drive formatted and installed Windows 7 replacing my XP.

Would it be possible to recover the uninstalled Chrome using data recovery software?

Secondly when you delete and uninstall a file or format your disk to replace
your OS is it really wiped out from your hardware or does it just go to some 'hard to reach place'

Comment: You already asked the same question before ([Is It Possible to Recover Specific Files Lost Due To Formatting and New OS Installation](http://superuser.com/q/975977)). Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Instead read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @Saeed - You have asked this same question, four times, in the last 48 hours.  If you continue to post the same question, only changing the wording slightly, you will lose your ability to post new questions.

Comment: Thanx but this question  is slightly different since one program was uninstalled before the formatting

Comment: @Saad - Does not change the fact.  You should be improving your current answers instead of asking the same question in a slightly different way.  My advice remains the same, if you continue to ask the same or similar questions, your ability to ask ANY question will be automatically revoked by the system.  Every single one of your questions is nearly identical to one another that isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Its highly unlikely you would be able to recover Google Chrome - but why not just download it again?

When you format a disk, the bits usually remain on the disk until overwritten, but the references to the file - sometimes including links to multiple parts of it in different places are erased, so finding it can be hard - and the file (usually) won't have a meaningful name - when you are talking about a program you are talking about lots of files.  I do note there are different types of formatting - some are more thorough - and delete more data then others.

Deleting a file will vary quite a bit on settings and OS - it can be that the file is simply moved into a "deleted/trash" area until purged, or it may be made available for overwriting immediately.

Comment: I Need The Search History I Lost Recovering That Browser Would Mean Recovering All Files Including Those Of Archived History

Comment: What can be recovered depends how long you performed the format.  If it was yesterday it might be possible, if it was months ago, then your chances are less then 0%

Comment: For you, the answer is no.  For a forensic expert there is a tiny chance. (for a start you dont need the program, only the file containing the history - indeed it is theoretically possible to recover only some of that file and get the info you need. You are talking hundreds to low thousands of dollars for an attempt with no guarantee of success.  (photorec or recuva might work if you know exactly what to look for, as might a raw disk search)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to recover data have a look at Hirens boot cd a free download, there is a program on there that I used before on my daughters laptop to recover data from an OS that had failed then had been reformatted when rebuilt. You will not necessarily get it all back but some. It took a few days and attempts but I got about 20 - 30% of her data back. Coarse work, photo's video and music though some of the pictures were just thumbnails.

Hope that helps and good luck.